# Error in SQL odbc_exec "Syntax error in UPDATE"

Tags: php, sql, odbc

Im running into an "odbc_exec(): Syntax Error in UPDATE" error when attempting to run my SQL code. Maybe there's a syntax error Im missing but I've checked it over and over and cannot find anything wrong with it.

```
if(!empty($_POST['materialsreason'.$i]))
{
$sqlnumerodos="UPDATE HotPartLog
SET MaterialsReason='".$_POST['materialsreason'.$i]."'
WHERE Date= '".$_SESSION['datearr'][$i]."'";
$resultdos=odbc_exec( $cnx, $sqlnumerodos);
}
```

This block is in my project and works fine but the above one will not.

```
if($_POST['selectcell'.$i]=='Closed')
{
    $dbname='C:\Users\irgcbk\Documents\hotpartdb.mdb';
    $db = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=$dbname; Uid=''; Pwd='';");
    $cnx=odbc_connect('ReceivingODBC', 'root', '');
    $sql="UPDATE HotPartLog
    SET CompletionStatus='Closed'
    WHERE Date= '".$_SESSION['datearr'][$i]."'";
    $result=odbc_exec( $cnx, $sql);
       }
```

Comment: Where are you defining `$cnx` for the first block?

Comment: It's in the bottom block. The bottom code is right above the first.

Comment: And are you sure that block is executing, i.e. is it passing the `if` test? If you're reusing those same connection details it's best to not define the connection in a place where it might not be set (even if that isn't the solution here)

Comment: Yep I echoed inside the if to check it was going through. Thanks for the advice though. I took all of the connection code and placed it outside

Comment: @Bulk If you didnt see I made a mistake in my post, its saying theres an issue with the UPDATE statement. Can you take a look at it?

Comment: I can't see any obvious syntax error either - can you `var_dump` the contents of `$_POST['materialsreason'.$i]` and `$_SESSION['datearr'][$i]`?

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), which is probably also the cause of your error.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I had to place "Date" in square brackets since it is a reserved word in Access

Answer (score -1):

I think you have not got a space between your variable and the WHERE. Always start by echoing out the actual sql you have generated and these sorts of problems are easy to spot.

Comment: false. there's new lines, which will be treated as spaces by the sql parser.

Comment: Whatever. The simple point I was trying to make was that he should dump the sql string and show us what was actually being sent to the db.

Comment: @DavidSoussan UPDATE HotPartLog SET Materials Reason='Test' WHERE Date= '03/04/2015 03:00:35 pm'

Comment: Agie, if that is the real query string then the problem is the gap between SET Materials Reason='Test'. The gap is the syntax error. SET MaterialsReason='Test' is what you need.

Comment: Thanks for the down vote by the way. I don;t think I deserved it as my main point was to always dump the sql string to see what is really being sent to the db.